# Proving $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f''(x)|^2dx\leq \left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}\cdot\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f''''(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $f$ be 2$\pi$ periodic. I want to show that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f''(x)|^2dx\leq \left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}\cdot\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f''''(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}$$ where we take $f$ to be $C^4$.

My initial thought was to use Fourier series expansions and apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I am not sure how exactly to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Using integration by parts, we get
\begin{align}
\int^\pi_{-\pi} f''(x)f''(x)\ dx = f''(x)f'(x)\big|_{-\pi}^\pi-\int^\pi_{-\pi}f'''(x)f'(x)\ dx = -\int^\pi_{-\pi}f'''(x)f'(x)\ dx.
\end{align}
Perform integration by parts one more time, then ... I will let you finish the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is like
\begin{align*}
\int|f''(x)|^{2}dx&=\sum|\widehat{f''}(m)|^{2}\\
&=\sum|m|^{4}|\widehat{f}(m)|^{2}\\
&\leq\left(\sum|m|^{8}|\widehat{f}(m)|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum|\widehat{f}(m)|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\sum|\widehat{f}(m)|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum|m^{4}\widehat{f}(m)|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\int|f(x)|^{2}dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum|\widehat{f^{(4)}}(m)|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\int|f(x)|^{2}dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int|f^{(4)}(x)|^{2}dx\right)^{1/2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: You should probably use discrete variables.

Comment: Yes, yes, just made that mistake.